# Parse comma-delimited string into vectors based on leading character

Tags: r, stringr

Given a string:

```
vals <- "-AB, CV, CL, -TS"
```

I would like to *efficiently* parse `vals` into two vectors (let's call them `negative` and `positive`), one containing the values prefixed by `-`, and the others not. One catch is that I would also like to remove the `-` indicator.

Desired result:

```
> negative
[1] "AB" "TS"
> positive
[1] "CV" "CL"
```

Bonus points for a compact answer.

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck? Split the string into pieces using `strsplit` or (`str_split` if you prefer), use `grepl`/`str_detect` to check each piece for `-` and sort accordingly, then remove the `-` with `sub` or `str_replace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
s <- trimws(strsplit(vals, ",")[[1]])
negative <- s[grepl("^-", s)]
positive <- s[!grepl("^-", s)]
```

Alternatively you can use pure regex this way

```
library(stringr)
negative <- as.vector(str_match_all(vals, "-\\w+")[[1]])
positive <- as.vector(str_match_all(vals, "(?<!-)(?<=^|,| )\\w+")[[1]])
```

Comment: Thanks! All good answers but yours works best for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
v <- trimws(strsplit(vals, ",")[[1]])

positive <- v[!startsWith(v, '-')]
negative <- substring(v[startsWith(v, '-')], 2)
```

Which outputs:

```
> negative
[1] "AB" "TS"
> positive
[1] "CV" "CL"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `grep` with `value = True` option, also since your data has leading spaces, to remove them you may use `trimws`. I am using `strsplit` here with "," as a separator. Using `zeallot` library just to assign everything in one step.

```
library(zeallot)
c(negative, positive) %<-% list(grep("^-",trimws(strsplit(vals,",")[[1]]), value=T), grep("^[^-]",trimws(strsplit(vals,",")[[1]]), value=T))
```

**Output**:

```
#> negative
#[1] "-AB" "-TS"
#> positive
#[1] "CV" "CL"
```